# Create table in databricks fails

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I just created a schema in Azure Databricks and I see I have Admin rights to the catalog. However when I try to create a table in schema I get below error. What wrong am i doing? I think I have the rights to create table if I can create schema

> Operation failed: "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make
> sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including
> the signature.", 403, GET, AuthenticationFailed, "Server failed to
> authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
> is formed correctly including the signature.
> RequestId:a159b290-a01f-003c-452c-a0b41d000000
> Time:2023-06-16T08:27:52.7989722Z"

Command I ran after schema:

```
%sql
CREATE Table IF NOT EXISTS
main.auditlogs.Customer_Logs
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error might be for the following reasons.

- It might be the due to the permissions on the unity catalogue.
  You mentioned that you created schema successfully but getting this error while creating the table.
  So, as per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-tables#requirements-1), make sure **you have the permission for `CREATE TABLE` on the table schema(`main.auditlogs`) of unity catalogue** as well.
- Recheck the Authorization credentials and ensure they are not expired if you are using PAT or Service principal.
- Make sure you **enable the hierarchical namespace** in the storage account settings.
  [image]

  Go through this [similar issue](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009e0giWSAQ/unity-catalog-set-up-unable-to-create-table) for better understanding.

Comment: what that has to do with storage account?

Comment: Unity catalogue will be created with GEN2 storage account and if the hierarchical namespace is not enabled then it means its a blob storage. So make sure you enabled it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/get-started#requirements

Comment: Ok, thats might be missing. If I say i am not sure what storage account was associated while creating the metastore.. How can I find the storage account where hirerachial namespace needs to be enabled

Comment: **AFAIK**, using REST API can be one way for getting the storage account name that was associated with unity catalogue. Get the details of unity catalogue by using REST API in this https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/catalogs/get. You can find storage_location in the properties of it. But I am not sure as I didn't tried it.